# Code that detects changes on itself

Tags: code-challenge

**Challenge:** Write a piece of code that only runs when the code is not being altered. If you change anything, the code should detect this and deny running. Of course, it should not be possible to just alter the detection mechanism (since this is a change in itself).

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! I'm afraid the specification of your challenge is missing a few details. For a start, all challenge need an objective winning criterion to determine which answer is best. However, even with that, it's not entirely clear what sort of changes are allowed. Surely, if I replace the entire program with `print "Hello, World!"` that's not possibly detectable. I recommend posting your idea [in the sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2140/8478) so the community can help you flesh it out and turn this into a great challenge. :)

Comment: In addition to Martin's comment, this is a borderline dupe of [Programming a Pristine World](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/63433/42963).