# Quining a Pristine World

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source, quine, pristine-programming

This challenge is based off of [Helka Homba](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/26997/helka-homba)'s question [Programming a Pristine World](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/63433/programming-a-pristine-world). From that question, the definition of a pristine program is:

> Let's define a *pristine program* as a program that does not have any errors itself but will error if you modify it by removing any contiguous substring of N characters, where `1 <= N < program length`.
>
> For example, the three character Python 2 program
>
> ```
> `8`
> ```
>
> is a pristine program <sup>([thanks, Sp](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25274283#25274283))</sup> because all the programs resulting from removing substrings of length 1 cause errors (syntax errors in fact, but any type of error will do):
>
> ```
> 8`
> ``
> `8
> ```
>
> and also all the programs resulting from removing substrings of length 2 cause errors:
>
> ```
> `
> `
> ```
>
> If, for example, `` `8 `` had been a non-erroring program then `` `8` `` would not be pristine because **all** the results of substring removal must error.
>
> **Notes:**
>
> - Compiler warnings do not count as errors.
> - The erroring subprograms can take input or give output or do anything else as long as they error no matter what eventually.

Your task is to create a program of non-zero length that prints its own source code exactly, follows the [rules for a proper quine](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4877/what-counts-as-a-proper-quine), and is pristine.

Shortest answer in bytes for each language wins.

Comment: I'm assuming languages that don't error can't compete?

Comment: @ATaco Unfortunately yes. Other languages, such as lisp, have the syntax structured in such a way that making a useful pristine program is impossible.

Comment: RIP Actually/Seriously

Comment: 'Shortest answer in bytes for each language wins.' I am not sure about short being the best measure for a pristine program.

Comment: @P.Siehr What would you reccomend instead?

Comment: Difficult question. I have thought about it for some time after I read your challenge. If you see the measure as something that measures the difficulty or complexity of the answer, than it would grow proportional to length (longest) and not inversely proportional (shortest). Then again, that is contrary to 'shortest quine'.

Comment: I'd actually say the longest pristine program is a better accomplishment.

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 132 bytes

```hs
q x=if length x==132then putStr x else fail[];main=q$(++)<*>show$"q x=if length x==132then putStr x else fail[];main=q$(++)<*>show$"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/v1ChwjYzTSEnNS@9JAPItjU0NirJSM1TKCgtCS4pUqhQSM0pTlVIS8zMiY61zk3MzLMtVNHQ1ta00bIrzsgvV1Gi3IT//wE)

This is an extension of the quine

```hs
main=putStr$(++)<*>show$"main=putStr$(++)<*>show$"
```

which works by concatenating the data string with a quoted version (by using `show`) of itself and printing the result. However, this is not pristine as any characters in the data string can be removed without failing and also the `$(++)<*>show$` or `(++)<*>` part could be dropped without the program breaking.

To fix this, a custom print function `q` is defined which checks the length of the given string and calls `fail` if it's shorter than 132. This catches the removing of any sequence from the data string and also the removals of `$(++)<*>show$` or `(++)<*>`, as in both cases the resulting string passed to `q` is shorter.

In `q` the number `132` could be shortened to `1`, `13`, `32` or `2`, but in each case again `fail` is called.

As far as I can tell, the removal of any other substring causes either an syntax or type error, so the program does not even compile in the first place. (Haskell's strict type system comes in handy here.)

**Edit:** Thanks to Ørjan Johansen and Shelvacu for pointing out a flaws!

Comment: I'm afraid `fail[]|length x/=122` can be removed. `fail[]:[putStr x|length x==122]` might work better.

Comment: Argh, no, then `|length x==122` could be removed. `if length x==122 then putStr x else fail[]` perhaps?

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Good catch, I had an `if then else` before but thought I could shorten it.

Comment: `putStr x` can become `p x`, which when I tried on my system ran for a very long time before I killed it, I suspect the tail call recursion was optimized, so it's an infinite loop. I don't know enough haskell to give any suggestions on how to fix it.

Comment: @Shelvacu Whoops. Renaming `p` to `q` should fix that.

Comment: @Shelvacu Good catch, it's fixed now as Ørjan Johansen suggested.

Comment: `<$>` within the data segment should presumably be `<*>` to match the code, otherwise it's not a quine.

Comment: @Shelvacu Thanks again, this was a copy-paste error.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 113 bytes

```python
for[]in{113:[]}[open(1,"w").write((lambda s:s%s)('for[]in{113:[]}[open(1,"w").write((lambda s:s%%s)(%r))]:a'))]:a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Py2/KDo2M6/a0NDYKjq2Njq/IDVPw1BHqVxJU6@8KLMkVUMjJzE3KSVRodiqWLVYU0OdNB0gLapFmpqxVonqYPL/fwA)

#### How it works

We can’t easily use multiple statements since the second one could be deleted, so we start with a single-expression quine:

```python
print((lambda s:s%s)('print((lambda s:s%%s)(%r))'))
```

To protect it against substring deletions, we use `open(1,"w").write` instead of `print`.  In Python 3, `write` returns the number of written characters, which we will verify is `113` to ensure that no part of the string was deleted.  We do this by looking up the return value in the dictionary `{113:[]}`, and looping over the result with `for[]in…:a`, which will fail if we didn’t get an empty iterable or if the `for` statement is deleted.

Comment: Could you give an explanation of how your code works?

Comment: @Shelvacu Yeah, added.

Answer (score 4):

## [Standard ML (MLton)](http://www.mlton.org/), <s>204</s> <s>182</s> 189 bytes

```ml
val()=hd[(fn s=>let val$ =s^"\""^String.toString s^"\"]"val(189,%)=(size$,$)in print%end)"val()=hd[(fn s=>let val$ =s^\"\\\"\"^String.toString s^\"\\\")\"val(189,%)=(size$,$)in print%end)"]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87N0c3NKcnP@/@/LDFHQ9NWIy1PodjWLie1RAEooKhga2wCpFUUbIvjikuKNJIzihQ145DYIF1GxhY6qkCtigraOal56SUZGqkVBTn5Kakqmjoqmpl5CgVFmXklqql5KZpK9LHl/38A)

For MLton, full SML programs are either expressions delimited and terminated by `;` (e.g. `print"Hello";print"World";`) or declarations with the `var` and `fun` keywords (e.g. `var _=print"Hello"var _=print"World"`) where `_` is a wild card which could also be replaced by any variable name.

The first option is useless for pristine programming because `;` on its own is a valid program (which does nothing, but doesn't error either). The problem with the second approach is that declarations like `var _=print"Hello"` can be shortened to just `var _="Hello"` (or even `var _=print`) because the declaration with `var` works as long as the right-hand side is a valid SML expression or value (SML is a functional language, so functions can be used as values too).

At this point, I was ready to declare pristine programming in SML impossible, when by chance I stumbled upon *pattern matching* in `val`-declarations. It turns out that the syntax for declarations is not `val <variable_name> = <expression>` but `val <pattern> = <expression>`, where a pattern can consist of variable names, constants and constructors. As the `print` function has type `string -> unit`, we can use a pattern match on the `unit`-value `()` to enforce that the print function is actually applied to the string: `val()=print"Hey"`. With this approach, removing either `print` or `"Hey"` results in a `Pattern and expression disagree`-error.

With this way of pristine printing at hand, the next step is to write a quine, before finally some more save-guarding needs to be added. I previously used an easy SML quine technique (see the [revision history](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/140849/4)), but Anders Kaseorg pointed out a different approach which can save some bytes in his case. It uses the built-in `String.toString` function to handle string escaping and is of the general form `<code>"<data>"`, where `"<data>"` is an escaped string of the `code` before:

```ml
val()=(fn s=>print(s^"\""^String.toString s^"\""))"val()=(fn s=>print(s^\"\\\"\"^String.toString s^\"\\\"\"))"
```

This is a working quine but not yet pristine. First of all Anders Kaseorg found out that MLton accepts a single quote `"` as code without producing errors, which means we cannot have code ending in a quote as above. The shortest way to prevent this would be to wrap everything after `val()=` in a pair of parenthesis, however then the code could be reduced to `val()=()`. The second shortest way I found is to use `val()=hd[ ... ]`, that is we wrap everything into a list and return its first element to make the type checker happy.

To make sure that no part of the data string can be removed without being noticed, the pattern-matching in `val`-declarations comes in handy again: The length of the final string to be printed (and thus the program length) should equal 195, so we can write `let val t=... val 195=size t in print t end` in the body of the `fn` abstraction instead of `print(...)`. Removing a part of the string results in a length less than 189, thus causing a `Bind` exception to be thrown.

There is still an issue left: the whole `val 195=size t` check could simply be dropped. We can prevent this by expanding the check to match on a tuple: `val t=... val(216,u)=(n+size t,t)in print u end`, such that removing the check results in an unbound variable `u`.

Altogether, this yields the following 195 byte solution:

```ml
val()=hd[(fn s=>let val t=s^"\""^String.toString s^"\")"val(195,u)=(size t,t)in print u end)"val()=hd[(fn s=>let val t=s^\"\\\"\"^String.toString s^\"\\\")\"val(195,u)=(size t,t)in print u end)"]
```

Applying the golfing trick of using operator variable names like `!`, `$` and `%` instead of `n`, `t` and `u` in order to save some white space (see [this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/150560/56433)) leads to the final 182 byte version.

All other substring-removals which where not explicitly stated in the explanation should result in a syntax or type error.

*Edit 1:* `length(explode t)` is just `size t`.
*Edit 2:* Thanks to Anders Kaseorg for a different quine approach and pointing out a "vulnerability".

Comment: [−2 bytes](https://tio.run/##K87N0c3NKcnP@/@/LDFHQ9NWIy1PodjWLie1RAEooKJgWxynFKOkFBdcUpSZl65Xkg9hKECEQXoMLQx0VIEaizOrUlV0VDQz8xQKgEpKVFPzUjSVcJoaoxQTA8TYTIZJETb9/38A "Standard ML (MLton) – Try It Online") by writing `"\""` directly and using `String.toString` for escaping.

Comment: Wait, this is horrible: MLton seems to accept the program `"`, producing empty output ([TIO](https://tio.run/##K87N0c3NKcnP@/9f6f9/AA "Standard ML (MLton) – Try It Online")).

Comment: @AndersKaseorg Huh, that's strange. However it should be possible to fix this issue by using another `let ... in ... end`.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg I fixed the issue, hopefully without introducing new "vulnerabilities".

Comment: Actually I looked into MLton accepting `"` as a program, and it seems that bug was fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/MLton/mlton/commit/a2606d088b6729eed9fcf404b98e1a499d17f806), so maybe your 182 or my 180 is fine as long as you specify the unreleased Git version of MLton.

Comment: Furthermore, your fix isn’t sufficient on the released MLton, which also accepts `"]` as a program ([TIO](https://tio.run/##K87N0c3NKcnP@/9fKfb/fwA "Standard ML (MLton) – Try It Online")). (By the way, you have a `)` that should be `]`.)

Comment: @AndersKaseorg I think I just specify Moscow ML. `mosmlc` rejects unclosed string literals. Also I found a 178 byte version: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tYxLCoAwDAWvkkqFFnXhZxuPIohWLNQoTXDh5WvxDq4GhnmPj9AcQU5K6Z6DsWg2AsYxOIEsFGA/ZIIgTyzRLHtUNgsNKNOXmK7t6jIPFVTsH6drbT3BFT1J6Wi1xW/HKb0 "Standard ML (MLton) – Try It Online") , but I don't want to rewrite the explanation yet again.

Answer (score 3):

### Ruby, 78 bytes

```rb
eval(*[($>.write((s=%{eval(*[($>.write((s=%%{%s})%%s)-78).chr])})%s)-78).chr])
```

I wrote this when I thought of the challenge to make sure it was possible. It uses the same "wrapper" from [one of my answers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/63625/13400) to the original pristine challenge.

Explanation:

- `eval(*[` *expr* `])`

  This evaluates whatever *code* returns as a ruby program. This effectively tests that the string that *code* returns is a valid ruby program. Conveniently, ruby programs can be blank, or only consist of whitespace.

  The "splat" operator `*` allows you to use an array as arguments to a function. This also means that if `eval` is removed, the resulting program is `(*[` *expr* `])`, which is not valid ruby.
- `($>.write(` *str* `)-78).chr`

  `$>` is a short variable for STDOUT.

  `$>.write(foo)` writes foo to STDOUT and, importantly for this code, returns the number of bytes written.

  `$>.write(foo)-78`: Here `78` is the length of the program, and so if the program is not mangled, will also be the number of bytes written. Therefor, in the unmangled case, this will return zero.

  `num.chr` returns num as a character, eg `0.chr` will return a string containing a single null byte. In the unmangled program, this will give a string with a single null byte to `eval`, which is a valid ruby program that is a no-op.

  Also, the program can have a substring removed such that it's just `eval(*[(78).chr])` or `eval(*[(8).chr])`, which means that the numeric constant cannot end with any of the numbers (0, 4, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 26, 32, 35, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 59, 64, 95) because they are ascii codes for valid single-character ruby programs.
- `%{` str `}`

  This is a lesser-known syntax for string literals in ruby. The reason it's used here is that balanced pairs of `{}` can be used within the string, which means this syntax can contain itself. For example, `%{foo{bar}}` is the same as `"foo{bar}"`.
- `(s=%{` *data* `})%s`

  This defines the variable `s` which is the data of this quine, as a printf string.

  Assignments in ruby return what was assigned, so this is the same as first assigning `s` and then running `s%s`

  `%` on a string is syntatic sugar for ruby's equivalent of sprintf. The `%s` signifies where within the data the data itself should be embedded.

  This bit of code defines the data portion of the quine and embeds it within itself to create the full code.