# Tips for Golfing in Standard ML

Tags: tips

**Standard ML** (or golfier: SML) is a general-purpose, modular, functional programming language with compile-time type checking and type inference. <sup>(from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_ML))</sup>

Though you almost certainly will never win a code golf challenge with SML, (ab-) using it for golfing can nevertheless be quite `fun` (<- keyword for function declaration). So without further ado ...

## What tips do you have for golfing in Standard ML?

Please only post tips which are somewhat unique to SML. General golfing tips belong to [Tips for golfing in all languages](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5285/56433).

Comment: I don't use haskell but I believe the syntax for basics is quite similar, so https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19255/tips-for-golfing-in-haskell broadly applies

Answer (score 9):

## Use symbolic identifiers

From [*The Definition of Standard Ml (revised)* [PDF]](http://sml-family.org/sml97-defn.pdf), Section 2.4:

> An identifier is either *alphanumeric*: any sequence of letters,
> digits, primes (`'`) and underbars (`_`) starting with a letter or
> prime, or *symbolic*:  any non-empty sequence of the following symbols:
>
> ```
> !  %  &  $  #  +  -  /  :  <  =  >  ?  @  \  ~  ‘  ^  |  *
> ```
>
> In either case, however, reserved words are excluded. This means that for
> example `#` and `|` are not identifiers, but `##` and `|=|` are identifiers.

The important part (concerning golfing) is that you do not need white space between symbolic identifiers and alphanumeric identifiers or keywords.

#### Example

```ml
fun f a b c=if b then a else c
```

By replacing `f` by `$` and `b` by `!`, we can save 6 bytes:

```ml
fun$a!c=if!then a else c
```

Note, however, that a symbolic identifier needs white space when next to other symbols. That's why we cannot replace `a` and `c` in the above example to get to the same byte count:

```ml
fun f$b!=if b then$else!    (* syntax error because != is parsed as one token *)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [List functions](https://smlfamily.github.io/Basis/list.html#SIG:LIST.tl:VAL)

Lists are the standard data structure usually used recursively with `::` constructor. Indexing must be done using `nth`.

Short and maybe useful functions are

- `@`: append
- `hd`: head, but also try pattern matching
- `tl`: all but head
- `last`: tail
- `take`: first n elements
- `drop`: drop first n elements and return
- `rev`: reverse

Higher order functions:

- `map`: map
- `foldr`, `foldl`: fold and reverse fold
- `filter`: filter
- `exists`, `all`: exists, all bool cond

Comment: Be aware that using functions from a structure requires either to open the structure (`open List`) or to qualify the functions (`List.exists`). However, the following list functions are also available at [top level](https://smlfamily.github.io/Basis/top-level-chapter.html): `@, app, foldl, foldr, hd, length, map, null, rev, tl`.

Answer (score 1):

## Pattern matching in functions

Concise way to extract the values and write cases for recursive functions. Case statements are probably too long.

Extracting values:

```
fn(x,y)=>x+y   (* lambda fn *)
fun f x y=x+y  (* curried bound function *)
```

Recursive function with base case (this basic list sum is equivalent to `foldl op+ 0`):

```
fun f(x::L)=x+f L|f _=0
```

Answer (score 1):

## Use wildcard matching instead of explicit matching

This broadly applies to any pattern matching construct with a fallthrough or wildcard: in some situations you can use the wildcard to match a pattern instead of an explicit pattern.

Empty list example (with formatting for clarity):

```
fun f([]) = 0
  | f(x::L) = x + f L
```

versus matching with wildcard saving a byte:

```
fun f(x::L) = x + f L
  | f(_) = 0
```

Comment: Also note that the wildcard does not need parentheses and only needs a space when preceded by an alphanumeric identifier. That is, the last line can be `|f _=0` or also `| $_=0` when `f` is renamed to `$`. Likewise, `fun f _x=x` works, but `fun x_=x` does not.