# Vowels up, consonants down

Tags: code-golf, string

## Challenge

You will be given a string that can contain lowercase letters, uppercase letters, or spaces. You have to turn the vowels (a, e, i, o, u) in the string to upper case and consonants to lower case. This applies whether or not the letter was originally upper case or lower case. Spaces remain as is. Note that "y" is a consonant.

## Examples

```
Hello World -> hEllO wOrld
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXWYZ -> AbcdEfghIjklmnOpqrstUvwxyz AbcdEfghIjklmnOpqrstUvxwyz
```

## Info

- The input string can contain letters A to Z, lowercase or uppercase, and spaces.

## Input

The string

## Output

The formatted string (Vowels uppercase and consonants lowercase).

Comment: Why on many challenges is "y" counted as a consonant ?

Comment: Because it is a consonant. (<pedantic> unless you're using international phonetic alphabet, where it's the front-high-rounded vowel /y/</pedantic>)

Comment: @bigyihsuan It's a bit more complicated than that. [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y): "In the English writing system, it mostly represents a vowel and seldom a consonant." As a child, I was taught that the vowels were "A, E, I, O, U, and sometimes Y," which could lead to viewing Y as "not really a vowel" because it's not *always* a vowel. Y is also a consonant in some very common words like "yes" and "you." But these are just guesses; I'm not entirely sure why Y is often not considered a vowel in coding challenges.

Answer (score 25):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org),  <s>55 ... 46</s>  45 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @KevinCruijssen*

```javascript
s=>Buffer(s).map(c=>c^(c^~68174912>>c)&32)+''
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@7/Y1s6pNC0ttUijWFMvN7FAI9nWLjlOIzmuzszC0NzE0tDIzi5ZU83YSFNbXf1/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmoaSR2pOTr5CeH5RToqSpiYXmmxiamZ@aVJySlp6RlZ2Tm5eQWFRcUlZeUVllYKjq6d/qJOzi5u7h5e3j69fQGBQcEhYeERkFNCc/wA)

#### How?

The constant \$68174912\$ is a bitmask describing the positions of the vowels:

```
00000100000100000100010001000000
     v     v     v   v   v
zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba`_^]\[
```

As per [the ECMAScript specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-signed-right-shift-operator-runtime-semantics-evaluation), the following expression:

```javascript
~68174912 >> c & 32
```

is equivalent to:

```javascript
~68174912 >> (c % 32) & 32
```

and therefore evaluates to \$32\$ for a consonant or \$0\$ for a vowel, no matter the case of \$c\$.

#### Commented

```javascript
s =>                   // s = input string
  Buffer(s)            // turn s into a buffer
  .map(c =>            // for each ASCII code c:
    c ^                //   change the case if:
      ( c              //     c is not in lower case
        ^              //     XOR
        ~68174912 >> c //     c is a consonant
      ) & 32           //
  ) + ''               // end of map(); coerce back to a string
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it is so beautiful!

Comment: Damn... I'll definitely try to use bit masks for future submissions...

Comment: Worth mention that space is treated as a consonant and don't turn into `\0`

Answer (score 17):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 49 bytes

Port of [my JS answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/201521/58563).

```c
f(char*s){for(;*s;s++)*s^=(*s^~68174912>>*s)&32;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NIzkjsUirWLM6Lb9Iw1qr2LpYW1tTqzjOVgNI1JlZGJqbWBoa2dkBlagZG1nX/s/MK1HITczM0yjLz0zRVKjmUlAAGaFQHB2rYKug5JGak5OvEO5flJOikJiamV@alJySlp6RlZ2Tm1dQWFRcUlZeUVml4Ojq6R/q5Ozi5u7h5e3j6xcQGBQcEhYeERmlZA00MU2jWBNEF5SWFIOZtf8B)

---

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 48 bytes

*A version suggested by @Neil*

This is abusing the way clang is dealing with the pointer post-increment.

```c
f(char*s){for(;*s;)*s++^=(*s^~68174912>>*s)&32;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYzHCsJAFADvfsXDg2wiHixYCAbsvXdFYd24MbommheNBf1013KaOQzDIkxQ25SSE7alrorKgzsu0VTUFBXD4VWWqLh6JdPRVCITjen6twjFY9pTWrYHB2rZ5OJYhgKPAMDvALhYQhaC1Y0QDkw6rjCAbiznvGYGN7e7vTjYx5OL3sW/3u6QK9U6o3yhWK5U641mq93t9QfD8WQ6mwe175ETVH48nj3861O@GRfURBnxPw)

Comment: Ah, this is a binary lookup table of ASCII characters mod 32. Smart.

Comment: @S.S.Anne Yes, exactly. (I've just added an explanation to my JS answer.)

Comment: GCC is too clever, but if you switch to clang then you can (currently) get away with incrementing the pointer in the assignment statement thus saving a byte.

Comment: @Neil Nice find!

Comment: GCC actually generates these for long strings of comparisons. Of course, they're in machine code, but still.

Comment: @S.S.Anne Yes, you are absolutely right: for `n==1|n==5|n==7|n==13`, it will test the bitmask `0x20a2` ([C to machine code](https://godbolt.org/z/CcWx2U)) provided that the code is compiled with at least `-O1`.

Answer (score 13):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 55 bytes

```python
lambda s:[[c,c.upper()][c in"aeiou"]for c in s.lower()]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYoxDoMwEAR7XnGiwZYSN@mQSJ0fpCAUBGzlIuOz7owihHi7A3Q7MxuX9KFwy655Zd9P77EHqdt2uAxmjtGy0l07AIayt0hz2TliOBjEePqdPeMUiRPIIsWRPQZ7PhYxkkYMdQEg0JxhN4xR6V3xrpySY0bGkJQrV9ngeoe1qsyXMCjWW6nzw3pP8CT24x8)

**Input**: A string/sequence of characters
**Output**: a list of characters.

#### Explanation

The solution converts the string to lower case, then convert all vowels to uppercase.

- `for c in s.lower()` converts the string to lower case, then loop through each character in the string.
- `[c,c.upper()][c in "aeiou"]` converts any vowel to uppercase, and consonant to lower case.
  `c in "aeiou"` evaluates to `0` or `1`, which is used to index into the list `[c,c.upper()]`.

Comment: Please could you share an explanation of how your `lambda` Python 3 function works, I'm new to code-golf and [my own Python 3 attempt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/201631/90593) relies on a `for` loop through list.

Comment: @AryanBeezadhur the main trick to working out what this answer does is figuring out which meanings the brackets have. The outer ones are a list comprehension, the first inner bracket is a 2 element list, and the second pair of inner brackets are list indexing (using the coercion from booleans to integers)

Comment: @Potato44 +1, thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't the output be a formatted string?

Answer (score 13):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, <s>20</s> 19 bytes

*-1 due to @NahuelFouilleul*

```perl
$_=lc;y;aeiou;AEIOU
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3jYn2brSOjE1M7/U2tHV0z/0/3@P1JycfIXw/KKclH/5BSWZ@XnF/3ULAA)

Convert everything to lower case, then change vowels to upper case.

Comment: can save one byte using `;` as transliterator delimiter and ommiting the last [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3jYn2brSOjE1M7/U2tHV0z/0/3@P1JycfIXw/KKclH/5BSWZ@XnF/3ULAA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Comment: Thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 10):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/), 53 bytes

```python
lambda s:[(c*2).title().strip('aeiou')[-1]for c in s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcTHDoIwAADQu1/R9EJrhESOJpi4994iB1alCG1ti4o/j77DE6VOOLMr4tyqzM@DyAeq5aKwbmNLU53FCFtKSyqQ4ceUFwZ2zaZHuAQhoAwor1IOZaLQCNeEpEwD1QDQbMP/0Eo5ZYgghXEF/SCMYnJPaPrIcsbFUypdvN6f8gs63V5/MByNJ9PZfLFcrTfb3f5wPJ8uV/gD)

Outputs a list of characters.

Here is an explanation of how it transforms each character `c`, with examples `c='A'` and `c='B'`:

```python
                'A'  'B'
(c*2)           'AA' 'BB'  # Two copies of c in a two-character string
.title()        'Aa' 'Bb'  # Title case: uppercase first letter and the rest lowercase
                           # This disregards the case of c
.strip("aeiou") 'A'  'Bb'  # Remove any leading or trailing lowercase vowels 'aeiou'
                           # For a two-character string, this removes all such letters
[-1]            'A'  'b'   # Take the last letter
```

**55 bytes**

```python
lambda s:[(c*2).title()[~(c in'aieouAEIOU')]for c in s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fci5DoIwAADQ3a9outAaZWA0wcQDFS@88EIGTilCW2lRcfDXUZc3PF7JhFGtjvVLnXm5H3pAdBwUNDWsSiKzCGHngwJAqOKRiJU9w7RsBbsxK8B/gXBroRPKS4lwgxeESiBaALa78CdUU0YoipHAuIaeH4RRfE1Iestyyvi9ELJ8PF/VG/T6g6ExGk/M6Wy@WFqr9Wa7s/fHw@kMvw)

If we were instead lowercasing vowels and uppercasing consonants, we wouldn't need the `~()` and would have 52 bytes.

Comment: [Alternative 53](https://tio.run/##DcTHDoIwAADQu1/R9EJLhIPeTDBx773XoSwpQou0KEj89uo7vKSQAWd15VtXFZHYdgkQjUtMclTqyNFr2JRURh7CX6PUNeJRnmlf7PMUOIAyIG5KWJQlmUS4kqSUSSSqABpN@B@aIacM@UhgjBUktuN6/j2g4SOKGU@eqZDZ650XH9Bqd7q9/mA4Gk@ms/liuVpvtrv98XA6wx8), Python 3 only: `lambda s:[max({*(c*2).title()}-{*'aeiou'})for c in s]`

Answer (score 7):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 15 bytes

```
lel"aeiou"_euer
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/Pyc1RykxNTO/VCk@tTS16P9/j9ScnHwdhfL8opwURQA)

#### Explanation

```
l         e# Read line
el        e# To lowercase
"aeiou"   e# Push this string
_         e# Duplicate
eu        e# To uppercase
er        e# Transliterate. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + Core utilities, <s>25</s> 23 bytes

```bash
tr aeiou AEIOU<<<${1,,}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6RIITE1M79UwdHV0z/UxsZGpdpQR6f2////iUnJKalp6RmZWdk5uXn5BYVFxSWlZeUVlVUKjk7OLq5u7h6eXt4@vn7@AYFBwaFh4RGRUQA)

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to a suggestion of Nahuel Fouilleul.*

Input is passed as an argument, output is on stdout.

Comment: saved 2 bytes using lowercase expansion [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6RIITE1M79UwdHV0z/UxsZGpdpQR6f2////Hqk5OfkK4flFOSkA "Bash – Try It Online")

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul Thank you -- did you mean something like this? TIO wasn't working on your link ("The permalink could not be decoded"), but I modified the code to use lowercase expansion as you suggested, and saved two bytes.

Answer (score 7):

## Java 8, <s>86</s> 34 bytes

```java
S->S.map(c->c^(c^~68174912>>c)&32)
```

-52 bytes by porting [*@Arnauld*'s JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/201521/52210), so make sure to upvote him!!

**Original 86 bytes answer:**

```java
s->{s=s.toLowerCase();for(var p:"aeiou".toCharArray())s=s.replace(p,p&=~32);return s;}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##dZDfT8IwEMff@SsuezBdlD3oGwsmiCgoP9Sh@CM@lK3AoLS1vQ2R4L8@uzlJiCFpmuvd9@776c1pSqvzaJGFnBoDPRqLTQUgFsj0hIYM@vkTIEAdiymEpAyM69v8tmIvgxTjEPogoJ6Z6vnG1I2HsitXTDepYcT1J1KTlGpQNYeyWCaOrTdnVDe0pmviunmHZopbQ6JO1FH9@@zU9TXDRAsw/jbzcyOVjLk1Kv1SGUewtLwl0ts7UPcXFplB4rQZ5xJGUvPIKWj/CgXCOIwm09l8wZdCfWiD6epz/QWNVmfweNG8vLpu39x2e/27@4dg@DR6fnndH2E/19L7KWzHAdjTAGyZofNvPwVvIS1XmMf5fkroYG2QLT2ZoKdsHbkgTkeoBGsAzvFO7B8UDxIs1M6x8EKyazjcUSJusx8)

**Explanation:**

```java
s->{                               // Method with String as both parameter and return-type
  s=s.toLowerCase();               //  Convert the entire String to lowercase
  for(var p:"aeiou".toCharArray()) //  Loop over the vowels as characters:
    s=s.replace(p,p&=~32);         //   And replace the lowercase vowels to uppercase ones
  return s;}                       //  Then return the modified String as result
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>9</s>  7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

Saved 2 using a variation of [Luis Mendo's CJam approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/201519/53748)

```
ØCŒHyŒu
```

A monadic Link accepting a list of characters which yields a list of characters.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wDOejkzwqj04q/f//vwdQLF8hPL8oJ0VHwdHf2x4A)**

#### How?

```
ØCŒHyŒu - Link: list of characters, S   e.g. "I am OK!"
ØC      - consonants                         "BCDF...XYZbcdf...xyz"
  ŒH    - split into two                     ["BCDF...XYZ", "bcdf...xyz"]
     Œu - convert (S) to upper-case          "I AM OK!"
    y   - translate                          "I Am Ok!"
```

Comment: This makes much more sense than the other "Jelly" answer. I fiddled with it and got an answer 1 byte longer: [`ØcṚŒHyŒl`](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wjOSHO2cdneRReXRSzv///z0VEnMV8rMVAQ) by doing the same thing but translating vowels.

Answer (score 6):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 33 bytes

```ruby
->s{s.downcase.tr"aeiou","AEIOU"}
```

Straightforward solution: downcase everything, then upcase vowels.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcrLCoJAFIDhfU9xOOvyDQoM71oSFkXhwstIgnmmGUebomefaBG0/b9fqFKbZmkWK/mSVk1TXxWSWYPAgrWkcI62G6YHfBuuBgnNBQPWdQRHEl2N@exX7xMTg1YtcbAzx/ODKE7g@ajGsr/9bfurCzsVVjGsRTptwaMTRGrDM0hHV8CXk@KswSEfc/MB)

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 14 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit prefix function.

```apl
⌈@(∊∘'aeiou')⌊
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn//1FPh4PGo46uRx0z1BNTM/NL1TUf9XT9T3vUNuFRb9@jruZHvWse9W45tN74UdvER31Tg4OcgWSIh2fw/zQFdY/UnJx8hfD8opwUdQA)

`⌊` lowercase

`⌈@(`…`)` uppercase **at** the following positions:

`∊∘'aeiou'` members of "aeiou"

Answer (score 6):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), <sup><s>41</s> <s>25</s></sup> 24 bytes

Saved 16 bytes thanks to [Surculose Sputum](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92237/surculose-sputum)!!!
Saved a byte thanks to [S.S. Anne](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/89298/s-s-anne)!!!

```
s/./\L&/g
y/aeiou/AEIOU/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/v1hfTz/GR00/natSPzE1M79U39HV0z9U//9/j9ScnHyFcP@inBQFsAxYQqGisioiMgoA)

Comment: [25 bytes](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/v1hfTz/GR00/natYPzoxNTO/NFY/JhTI///fIzUnJ18h3L8oJ0UBLOPo6ukfqlBRWRURGQUA)

Comment: @SurculoseSputum Ah, yes of course. Very nice - thanks! :-)

Comment: [24 bytes](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/v1hfTz/GR00/natSPzE1M79U39HV0z9U//9/j9ScnHyFcP@inBQFsAxYQqGisioiMgoA)

Comment: @S.S.Anne Interesting, `y` commands ("*Transliterate*" according to the docs) act sort of like `tr`. Nice one - thanks! :-)

Answer (score 6):

## x86-64 machine code, 21 bytes

(Or **20 bytes** for an x86-32 version with an explicit length input, allowing `dec/jnz` as the loop condition.  Using `cl` for a shift count makes it not a win to use `loop`, and 64-bit mode has 2-byte `dec` so it's break-even to make it explicit-length).

Callable as `void vucd_implicit(char *rdi)` with the x86-64 System V calling convention.  (It leaves RDI pointing to the terminating `0` byte if you want to use that bonus return value.)

```
# disassembly: objdump -drwC -Mintel
0000000000401000 <theloop>:
  401000:       b8 a0 bb ef fb          mov    eax,0xfbefbba0
  401005:       d3 e8                   shr    eax,cl
  401007:       30 c8                   xor    al,cl
  401009:       24 20                   and    al,0x20
  40100b:       30 c8                   xor    al,cl
  40100d:       aa                      stos   BYTE PTR es:[rdi],al
000000000040100e <vowel_up_consonant_down>:        # the function entry point
  40100e:       8a 0f                   mov    cl,BYTE PTR [rdi]
  401010:       84 c9                   test   cl,cl
  401012:       75 ec                   jne    401000 <theloop>
  401014:       c3                      ret
```

Notice that the function entry point is in the middle of the loop.  This is something you can do in real life; as far as other tools are concerned, `theloop` is another function that falls into this one as a tailcall.

This uses something like Arnauld's xor/and/xor idea for applying the lcase bit to an input character, instead of the more obvious `and cl, ~0x20` to clear it in the original, `and al, 0x20` to isolate it from the mask, and `or al, cl` to combine.  That would be 1 byte larger because `and cl, imm8` can't use the AL,imm special encoding with no ModRM.

Having the bitmap left-shifted by 5 so the bit we want lines up with 0x20 is also due to [@Arnauld's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/201508/vowels-up-consonants-down/201521#201521).  I had been planning to use `bt`/`salc` like in [a previous vowel/consonant bitmap answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/123194/user-appreciation-challenge-1-dennis/123458#123458) and mask that with `0x20` until I tried Arnauld's way and found it could be done even more efficiently.

NASM source ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVZrV9s4EP3uXzFfKAlN2DjQLgeXnoWUlLS8yqO09LA@sq0koorklew8@PPsSLKdNEALPoeESJqrq5k71yJa01HEZ01B9Oj@HvAJAugQzpkYQCzFmIqMSQE7cD7TX2G69bb5dtMr1o0lS2Ccx0nIRilnMctq8ZAoWFMJqz9cRKfLixqg2R0NM1AaAwZcRoRjwITyME9D3F5LQUQWJnIivGxIuZTptgV@9hNABQMRy0YkdcTmK66/f7v6enlxfvbl9OT46PDzp97Bx@7@h87e7j9muisVMJHQqcnIhGVD2D3v9HoQv9rwIWGKxhmfWcyRHOMnJdMG@OZpLX26vwjevYM3lgImmUKeOlQ8HvCYaGpovvSMNlhOTCgwDT5kElJFNVVjCq1puwWrsGpB9VCVJGP@AGf3EF659YgyRMACmKqSGazpocx5sgYRBU0d06k0oIQ/gomgGJWwfh81VBsR/fP9@7iOu8Q2koikiLS7LkUyLTnJ6EMWz9i1z1n6a1KB9UFQmtDEZSKTOnoyo4YYrlDUe0KP2ws1j5HDD9TzjR3LqM7cWMztwK24g0K99rfCtHkBSI6NQVH6UngryK31hw4Ix7739NS2F2C3Ea3zkUkYyYBTAe93wPfW533j@CYV32C5CH934d@yFtg7nGKrPky/i9N5VMSt7q4uJk8RMaBNPWT9zCjRzO7g8WxQPErLoOvVZhUYmOrg2SdEI3GtzRGEiWwAVm7CODeCI8CJGmDTCM0GgiYg8lFElUO@JQDrQoqQ8HRISv9BSe9AKjWzPsYE2NmIZlBrNdtv6niW4NmOgJOtpnUDFJGLK7o@@W3XR7860V@2jIUfQR91nGNirQ1E2Qv9yS/5IIaxqMKdZEL1o/ak2e@IvpxplEEJi0lYbqNOF7Nvuh47vuZfGu@rGees163kO6eXRycf9mFnBzbarisJj5/2OX8Pv6TgM2M92tW2BciqNe121wGOZQZkTBgnEaem2G83m6bzR5gOb4VyTd0mUVSaIH4sb9Lec5MldtNvAIljiQ2D@UU9d7rrCCbQ1JZ8KOHPMLXbHO3hT45WIFmP8uai3rZZ6x2dHvY6vYvwcP/448XBgumYWDI3Hdv4C@c2P6tBy7/yI/f7Pnj0KY0p1BlRmee@nKEEKwntm/fY6cXZee96HzbdC0nl1MplutG2@dhoV4VYd7sGVpDU3AJ@KJ2@3oTXsLnm35hwlBNmH1t9/MO/matXVYu3cPFWsVgtLra7m3e2ooMczaK4skBNoDSQTH0BzW83DCQ6wCNZNZpsefOy6Uyhodaqq828pRApRiU1/Wrc1XGusGpC0RRTpbHoUeGUsZFZ04FDE9rVUsO3wK7GEhpXY8GCAt1xorRhZ5byhce0IzHe6p68XC3E6IUYVyJ7o7F0w/D4LJwoltGFabOJv/jbHDpyrzo903bfMos2tmYaypWrUeQ1RA3WvdKzjceYDilEs7vXA7w94n8FHOLjxdT0t5GX8TqrNV1eQ2cFkOHj2BcDDG@BrelW65eGtNA1TK4QTIec/aS1gl0dCk62oPag@FEd1UC3N/wCprAaQ9YAhgMl87SGFlJfzIR3f39AOZdwJRW@/3F558N@9@NB79Pnw6Pjk9MvZ@cXl1@vvn2/BhLF2FuDIbv9yUdCpv8pneXjyXR29z8) with a test caller that does strlen on a command line arg and uses a write() system call afterward)

```
global vowel_up_consonant_down
theloop:
                                             ; consonant bitmap
    ;          ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA@    For indexing with ASCII c&31 directly
    mov   eax, 111110111110111110111011101b << 5   ; line up with the lcase bit
                                             ; the low bit is 1 to preserve 0x20 ' '
    shr   eax, cl               ; AL & 0x20 is how the lowercase bit *should* be set
    xor   al, cl                ; bitdiff = (mask>>c) & c
    and   al, 0x20              ; isolate the lowercase bit
    xor   al, cl                ; flip the lcase bit if needed
    stosb                       ; and store
vowel_up_consonant_down:
    mov   cl, [rdi]
    test  cl, cl
    jnz  theloop               ; }while(c != 0)
    ret
```

---

### Variants

#### no spaces: 19 bytes

If we didn't need to handle spaces (ASCII 0x20), we enter the function at the top, with the `mov cl, [rdi]` load at the top, but still leave the loop condition at the bottom.  So we'd load and re-store the terminating `0`, and the XOR that produced it would set ZF.  The low bit of the bitmap would be 0 instead of 1.

```
vucd_pure_alphabetic:
.loop:
    mov   cl, [rdi]
   ...               ; same, but with bitmap[0] => 0
    xor   al,cl
    jnz  .loop       ; mask>>0 leave the terminating 0 unmodified; xor sets ZF
```

#### Upper-case-only input, like the A to Z in the question indicates: 19 bytes

(Or 17 without spaces either.)

If we can assume the lower-case bit was already cleared on input ASCII bytes, we can save one XOR (and change the other one to an OR)

```
    ...
    shr   eax, cl
    and   al, 0x20
    or    al, cl
    ...
```

---

#### Using the `bt` instruction:

Normally testing a bitmap is a job for the `bt` instruction, but where we're not branching on the result, it turns out to be cheaper to shift it, even though that means we can't easily use the `loop` instruction.  (I haven't gone back to this idea to re-golf it after realizing we need to handle spaces).

I suspect there's room for more golfing, but the first version of this I tried was

```
vucd:
.loop:
    mov   dl, [rdi]
    ;          ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA@    1-indexed using ASCII codes directly
    mov   esi, 111110111110111110111011101b   ; consonant/vowel bitmap for use with bt
    bt    esi, edx              ; CF = mask & (1U << (c&31))
%if CPUMODE == 32
    salc                        ; 1B   only sets AL = 0 or 0xFF.  Not available in 64-bit mode
%else
    sbb   eax, eax              ; 2B   eax = 0 or -1, according to CF.
%endif
    xor   al, dl
    and   al, 0x20              ; just the lowercase bit
    xor   al, dl
    loop .loop
    ret
```

Not re-tested after tweaking to handle spaces.

`bt` + `salc` in 32-bit mode costs the same as `shr reg,cl` + the extra `test cl,cl` that's needed because we can't use `loop`.  So I think this is also 21 bytes.  But 32-bit mode explicit-length can just `dec/jnz` a reg other than `cl` for a 20-byte total.

`mov esi, imm32` can be hoisted out of the loop, or we can use EAX.  Neither affects byte count, only efficiency or the calling-convention.

Answer (score 5):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>75</s> \$\cdots\$<s>72</s></sup> 71 bytes

Added 4 bytes to fixed a bug.
Saved a byte thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!

```c
u;f(char*s){for(;*s;*s++=u-65&&u-69&&u-73&&u-79&&u-85?*s|32:u)u=*s&95;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/7/UOk0jOSOxSKtYszotv0jDWqsYiLS1bUt1zUzV1ICkJYg0NwaTYLaFqb1WcY2xkVWpZqmtVrGapal17f/cxMw8Dc1qLpBZChnRsbZKHqk5OfkK4f5FOSlK1hDxkmhDo1hrrtzU3OSCSo0SnQwdQyNNa66Cosy8kjQNJdViBV07BSWdEqBYmkYJikxMHkS89j/U3HyguQA)

Answer (score 5):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>58</s> \$\cdots\$ 58 bytes

```c
f(char*s){for(;*s;)*s++=index("aeiou",*s|32)?*s&95:*s|32;}
```

I tried to find a pattern in the vowels' representations using the modulo operator but nothing short enough. Instead, use `strchr`.

*Fixed a bug kindly pointed out by [Noodle9](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9481/noodle9) at the cost of 3 bytes.*
*-1 byte thanks to [Noodle9](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9481/noodle9)!*
*-1 byte thanks to [Surculose Sputum](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92237/surculose-sputum)!*
*-1 byte thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NIzkjsUirWLM6Lb9Iw1qr2FpTq1hb2zYzLyW1QkMpMTUzv1RJR6u4xthI016rWM3S1ArMsa79n5lXopCbmJmnUZafmaLJVc2lAAQg0xQyUnNy8qNjFWwVlDxATIVw/6KcFAWwYQqOrp7@oUrWYNVpGmClmhBeQWlJMVyg9j8A)

Answer (score 5):

## x86 platform-independent machine code, 46 bytes.

Expects the string pointer to be passed in `eax`, trashes `ebx` and `edx`.
Entry point is located at 0x26.

Hex dump:

```
BA 22 82 20 00 D3 EA F6 C2 01 74 0B 8D
51 9F 83 FA 19 8D 59 E0 EB 09 8D 51 BF
83 FA 19 8D 59 20 0F 46 CB 88 08 40 0F
BE 08 85 C9 75 D3 C3
```

Disassembly:

```
00000000  BA22822000        mov edx,0x208222
00000005  D3EA              shr edx,cl
00000007  F6C201            test dl,0x1
0000000A  740B              jz 0x17
0000000C  8D519F            lea edx,[ecx-0x61]
0000000F  83FA19            cmp edx,byte +0x19
00000012  8D59E0            lea ebx,[ecx-0x20]
00000015  EB09              jmp short 0x20
00000017  8D51BF            lea edx,[ecx-0x41]
0000001A  83FA19            cmp edx,byte +0x19
0000001D  8D5920            lea ebx,[ecx+0x20]
00000020  0F46CB            cmovna ecx,ebx
00000023  8808              mov [eax],cl
00000025  40                inc eax
00000026  0FBE08            movsx ecx,byte [eax]
00000029  85C9              test ecx,ecx
0000002B  75D3              jnz 0x0
0000002D  C3                ret
```

byte count = 0x2E = 46

Comment: :( bytes in decimal please

Comment: Two possible options for golfing that `bitmap >> (c&31)` test of the immediate bitmap: use `bts edx, ecx`, or use a bitmap that's already shifted by 1 so the bit you want goes into CF instead of the low bit of EDX.  (Except that fails for CL&31=0 which doesn't clear CF).  Also, you aren't taking any advantage of AL,imm8 short forms like 2-byte `test al, imm8`.  Use ESI as the input pointer so you can `lodsb` / `xchg eax,ecx` to do `cl = *esi++`  Or with BTW, you don't need the byte in CL so it's also better for that reason.

Comment: @ASCII-only: I fixed the title line of this answer to count in decimal.  I think that's allowed even within codegolf's strict rules about not editing other people's *code*, only fixing formatting and maybe explanations.

Comment: @Krysztof: Turns out a right-shift works at least as well as `bt` / `salc` when you use the ASCII code directly, so it's 1-indexed.  I'm not sure why you need so much branching and cmov, though.  I think you're separately doing `c-'a'` and/or `c-'A'`.  You can just mask away the lower-case bit ([What is the idea behind ^= 32, that converts lowercase letters to upper and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54585515)); Anyway [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/201508/vowels-up-consonants-down/201568#201568) on this Q ended up branchless other than the loop, 21 bytes.

Comment: You also don't need a `movsx` load.  This is code-golf: performance isn't important so we don't need to avoid false dependencies or partial-register stalls (e.g. from using a 32-bit `cmov` after writing 8-bit partial registers).

Answer (score 5):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 9 bytes

```
T`vVL`VVl
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/PyShLMwnISws5/9/j9ScnHyF8PyinBQA) Explanation:

```
T`v`V
```

Lowercase vowels get uppercased.

```
T`V`V
```

Uppercase vowels also get uppercased, to avoid being matched later.

```
T`L`l
```

All other uppercase letters get lowercased.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E),  <s>9</s>  6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

Saved 3 using [Luis Mendo's CJam approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/201519/53748)

```
lžMDu‡
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/5@g@X5fSRw0L///3SM3JyVcIzy/KSdFRcPT3tgcA)** (Footer formats the resulting list of characters as a plain string)

#### How?

```
lžMDu‡         e.g. input="LowEr"  stack: []
l      - push lower-case (input)          ["lower"]
 žM    - push lower-case vowels           ["aeiou", "lower"]
   D   - duplicate                        ["aeiou", "aeiou", "lower"]
    u  - upper-case                       ["AEIOU", "aeiou", "lower"]
     ‡ - transliterate                    ["lOwEr"]
       - implicit print                   lOwEr
```

Comment: YES...! I was assuming this was Jelly...................................... I was about to come here and comment that I couldn't even find it in the code but now I understand why! Thanks.

Comment: I have a Jelly answer too :)

Answer (score 4):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <s>83</s> 82 bytes

```
func[s][v: charset"aoeiu"parse lowercase s[any[to v change t: v(uppercase t/1)]]s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYq7CgIxEAD7@4plK63ENq2F1jYWIUVINnqwZMPmcfj10QOxmxlGKc47ReuWZGbqOdjq7DAQXl4rNfRCa8eyC7BspMF/qVqf37YJjH3MT4JmYBx6Kb@hnc5H56qbRdfcIAHeiFngIcoRl3@9SCS4CiecHw)

Answer (score 4):

## [Io](http://iolanguage.org/), 72 bytes

Takes input as a special format.

```
method(x,x map(i,if("aeiou"containsSeq(i),i asUppercase,i asLowercase)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcyxCgIxEATQX1m22oV8gWBvYSdiYxMuKy7ksjHJcff3MWiKBzNTjFrfcrA9wekMz75Ke1ugwx2w@kzq9EXoRW3DxVLzmupNPqTsFHy95yxl8VV@7Wr7vzHzPKWotRFe0KEMcbIBhsfMZe4BmSEXTS2m/gU)

Answer (score 4):

## [Javascript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 97 bytes

```
s=>[...s].map(c=>{t="aeiouAEIOU";return(t.includes(c)?c.toUpperCase():c.toLowerCase())}).join('')
```

Takes a string, iterate over every chars and check if the char is a vowel. If so return the char in uppercase, otherwise in lowercase. Then join the return of the map with a void char.

- First post/answer here, if you see some errors or missed case, or just want to improve my code feel free to do so

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 93...77 bytes

Log:

- -5 bytes thanks to @Benji
- -14 bytes: switched to case insensitive matching and `.test()`

```javascript
s=>[...s].map(c=>/[aeiou]/i.test(c)?c.toUpperCase():c.toLowerCase()).join('')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/ZVsIwFEXf/QpwaqISnEW0IJOCMs/QgpY0xdbSpE0YHX69Vpe8uHg86@519rmWNtM49kwmIrOYb8g@lxMKQogP0ERjAMuJqKIRk04HURMJwgXAMImRoC3GiJfROAEw/pOLdL7OEFnUdIAkQR9Th1ObIJuOgQGkPLFtGupQz9bDEoRb/86/InfuiSXjujF@td7s1QLPRs5kEzzCOgkgM6AmDmWux8V0vliuQql0Jpu7f8gXHp@KpXKlWqs3mq12p9vrb6h5OTk9O7@4vIpdH0dkN/hBLKcmZcpAVbX1iBtV@ttxhKJf4bud3b3h/gGAz4e1Tq7e7LUKler750eqkQ2sgTS@3e9m2uly6TaRDJT@Nw)

```javascript
s=> // es6 arrow function
    [...s]. // split input string into array
        map(c => // another es6 arrow function, this time for a callback iterating over the array
             /[aeiou]/i // case insensitive regex
                .test(c)? // use a ternary operator to check if the character matches the regex
                    c.toUpperCase(): // if true return character to uppercase
                        c.toLowerCase()) // otherwise return lowercase
                            .join('') // join the array back into a string
```

Methods mentioned:

- [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
- [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: You could save a few bytes if you change /a|e|i|o|u/ -> /[aeiou]

Comment: right! thanks @Benji

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 68 bytes

```hs
import Data.Char
f=map(g.toLower)
g x|x`elem`"aeiou"=toUpper x|1<2=x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcnLEoIgFADQvV/BMC1q00ytY1Ha297Za@WtUEkQQkxq@nfqbE8GZU45d44JJbVBARho@xloLyECVDNtGxnKmuqWlyL7tTHlVMQYKJMVJkZGSlH9j06vS6wTwAqiNCtMI0EYrrc7TdKMPXIuCqmeujTVq7bvD@oP/GA4Gk@ms3m4WK7Wm@1uHx1Ox/MFux8)

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0 <s>[`-m`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/)</s>, <s>10</s> 7 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
u r\c_v
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&code=dSByXGNfdg&input=IkhlbGxvIFdvcmxkIg)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 50 bytes

```python
lambda s:bytes(c^(c^~68174912>>c%32)&32for c in s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcJZC4IwAADg937FEIoN7EGNLlDovu87InDqcqXT3LTsob@@@vjiXPgRMyQxLzKwQ@zagDdxLjwOnev/t1rXapWGpluWUzR0VDJ0EiXAAZQBjiQ3vcwOIGVxKiBChTihTECuAqVsKSogkCMksWJjx/XIzaf3RxCyKH4mXKTZ651/QKvd6fb6g@FoPJnO5ovlar3Z7vbHw@ms/AA)

Port of [Arnauld's JS answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/201521/78410) using bytes object in Python. Because Python's `>>` does not imply `%32` on its right argument, it must be done manually.

Answer (score 2):

## T-SQL, 48 bytes

```sql
SELECT TRANSLATE(LOWER(v),'aeiou','AEIOU')FROM t
```

Takes input from a pre-existing table *t* with varchar column *v*, [per our IO rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/5341#5341).

Converts the entire string to lowercase, then makes just the vowels uppercase. The function [`TRANSLATE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) works in SQL 2017 and later.

Answer (score 2):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>27</s> <s>23</s> 21 bytes

**Solution:**

```
`c$x-32*~^"aeiou"?x:_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/PyFZpULX2EirLk4pMTUzv1TJvsIqXikxKTklNS09IzMrOyc3L7@gsKi4pLSsvKKySsHRydnF1c3dw9PL28fXzz8gMCg4JDQsIjwySun/fwA)

**Explanation:**

Even nicer approach thanks to @ngn... either substract 0 or 32 from the input based on whether or not it's a vowel:

```
`c$x-32*~^"aeiou"?x:_ / the solution
                    _ / lowercase input
                  x:  / store as 'x'
          "aeiou"?    / lookup input in "aeiou" else null
         ^            / is null?
        ~             / not
    -32*              / multiply boolean list by -32 (yields 0 or -32)
   x                  / subtract from x
`c$                   / cast back to characters
```

**Notes:**

- **-6 bytes** thanks to @ngn

Comment: hint: `(-32*isvowel)+x` leads to a shorter solution than `@[;;;]`

Comment: i was thinking of `\`c$(-32*x in"aeiou")+x:_` but yours is even better :)

Comment: -2: `\`c$x-32*~^"aeiou"?x:_`

Comment: Thanks - I managed to golf another byte as I was writing up the explanation - let me update with your latest :)

Answer (score 2):

## [K4](https://kx.com/download/), 24 bytes

**Solution:**

```
.q.ssr/[;_v;v:"AEIOU"]@_
```

**Explanation:**

Replace each lowercase vowel with the uppercase equivalent.

```
.q.ssr/[;_v;v:"AEIOU"]@_ / the solution
                       _ / lowercase
                      @  / apply
.q.ssr/[;  ;         ]   / search/replace, iterate over vowels
            v:"AEIOU"    / store uppercase vowels as 'v'
         _v              / lowercase vowels
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org) 49 bytes

### [Try it!](https://tio.run/##BcFBCoAgEADAryyeFDSobkHWsR90lk3J2NpQxH5vM1eh6PqvhbmRsbd7JRobH4laOB@5CAULoBkHmAA1cfUJXfadJKXamk@uEKTYPBHDzokOodoP)

```
f=l->map(c->in(c,"aeiou") ? c-32 : c,lowercase.(l))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 20 bytes

```
K"aeiou"smrd}d+KrK1w
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/31spMTUzv1SpOLcopTZF27vI27D8//@SjFSFwFBPZ2@FpKL88jwFN/8IhazS3IJiBf8w1yAFkLSPY1SkQkp@OgA)

## Explanation

```
                       w=input()
K"aeiou"               K="aeiou"
        s              "".join(
         m              map(
          r              lambda d:r(
           d              d,
             d             d
            }             in
               K           K
              +            +
                 rK1       K.upper())),
                    w    w)
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 68 bytes

```python
lambda s:''.join([p.upper()if p in'aeiou'else p for p in s.lower()])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hcq7CsMwDEDRXxFZbC9eugW69w86JB0cIlMVxRJ@EPr1zmO8h6v/@pX06PE5dw7bsgYoozH@J5TspL6pYraOIihQMgFJmkEueHaUfCsUz7Jf28d1zZSqjXZ4IbPAWzKvg3P9AA)

Answer (score 2):

## Zsh `--extendedglob`, 39

```zsh
<<<${${(L)@}//(#m)[aeiou]/${(U)MATCH/}}
```

[Try it Online](https://tio.run/##DctJDoIwGEDhvaf4E1nQVS/AQhxRwRHFIS6AlrFQhjKI4ezI8n3J68pg8GQkl1TwTABtBU0JJT7jzqAoivSTfrKOZj3G8jRBb5uGvPrgEW/IUM2Fhvt@QBMPNMoYB4sXjIxlOy6hnh@EUcySlGd5UYqqbtpvB@p8sVytN9p2t9eNw/F0vlzN2/1hPV/jV1NGBETftAW/CJOshMbOPegCDk7lxsMf)

Code borrowed from the Zsh Manual, [Globbing Flags](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Globbing-Flags)

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), <del>94</del> 59 bytes

59 bytes(Saved 35 bytes thanks to @movatica). [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=PY49CgIxEIV7TzGm2gW1sZGVFcTGQitZLERkjLMSiUlIsv4gnsRGC628kLdxcMFm3rw3j4-5vYJEjd33QrTp5DQqI5afk13vSEaYsoVLA2BDJezZJOi3IYOh93hezKJXZrtMMyiMipD_mgCO06hNUiZiTFrbFsyt15umSFO-Xxs8DqihzKAGQD74b88qlu3ep7_qRDuxR_IjDNTZo0tkPlBMRFK2EtKayN8EkKnkZuEceSAdiIMa8bjWer_X-gU)

```scala
_.toLowerCase.map(c=>if("aeiou"contains c)c.toUpper else c)
```

---

94 bytes. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=PY_NTgIxFIXjlqVPcDMxGVgACzcGMySIqCgICvhHkJSxQLHTDv0BkfAkbnChG59In8Z2OiFpcu93c-49px_fMkQUHf70vTzjSySYN_jb2-ejGQ4VNBFhsM4AvOAxRAaySExkCSpCoFW_owRhk0GuBD1GFASJEmCBKBAWazvx0Cg0u5Mpmb3SiPF4LqTSi-Xb6h0qJ9XT2tn5Rf3yqtG8brVvbjvd3t3D_eOTB8UidKdEgnl4rok5iZkCxaGNBfWlzYM0VcZLEDSiGA6GO2-ulTNXAjE55iLKJnFyiSI2mRVlWaeys00m4xZ3-hK4r0FQ3nVfWo3zR7_PMCwo3uBLLKpI4kKE4nVoGh_5Qdmv-McJYAu1FIiFegrcQisFbaHnAMKgHG6cy2dat1tX_wE)

```scala
_.toLowerCase.map{case'a'=>'A';case'e'=>'E';case'i'=>'I';case'o'=>'O';case'u'=>'U';case c=>c}
```

Comment: [59 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=PY49CgIxEIV7TzGm2gW1sZGVFcTGQitZLERkjLMSiUlIsv4gnsRGC628kLdxcMFm3rw3j4-5vYJEjd33QrTp5DQqI5afk13vSEaYsoVLA2BDJezZJOi3IYOh93hezKJXZrtMMyiMipD_mgCO06hNUiZiTFrbFsyt15umSFO-Xxs8DqihzKAGQD74b88qlu3ep7_qRDuxR_IjDNTZo0tkPlBMRFK2EtKayN8EkKnkZuEceSAdiIMa8bjWer_X-gU)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>8</s> <s>7</s> 6 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to Kevin Cruijssen*

```
lžODu‡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/5@g@f5fSRw0L///3SM3JyVcIzy/KSXF09fQPBQA)

Comment: Fails when there are upper-case vowels present in the input

Comment: Also not sure why you're treating `y` as a vowel, usually it is not considered a vowel.

Comment: @JonathanAllan thanks, fixed the bug with uppercase vowels. Regarding your second comment,  y is *sometimes* not considered a vowel, but I sure wouldn’t say that’s “usual”. [Y is the sixth vowel letter according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y).

Comment: You can remove the surrounding map: [try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/5@g@f5fSRw0L///3SM3JyVcIzy/KSXF09fQPBQA).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 14 bytes

```
⭆↧Ｓ⎇№aeiouι↥ιι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRCO4BEil@yYWaPjkl6cWJScWp2p45hWUlkAkNDQ1dRRCUovyEosqNZzzS4E6lBJTM/NLlXQUMoFSoQUFUE0gXqampqb1//8eqTk5@Qrh@UU5KVz/dctyAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
  Ｓ             Input string
 ↧              Lowercased
⭆               Map over characters and join
     aeiou      Literal string `aeiou`
    №           Count occurrences of
          ι     Current character
   ⎇            If non-zero
            ι   Current character
           ↥    Uppercased
             ι  Else current character
                Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [W](https://github.com/A-ee/w) [`d`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14337/command-line-flags-on-front-ends/14339#14339), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/A-ee/w/wiki/Code-Page)

```
→d╧o╧╪0╨←
```

Uncompressed:

```
("aeiou":)Z
```

## Explanation

```
(           % Convert to lowercase
 "aeiou"    % All vowel strings
        :   % Duplicate
         )  % Convert to uppercase
          Z % Transliterate
```

Answer (score 1):

## Batch, <s>118</s> 115 Bytes

3 bytes saved thanks to Neil

```
@Set o=%*
@For %%A in (A E I O U b c d f g h j k l m n p q r s t v w x y z)do @Call Set o=%%o:%%A=%%A%%
@ECHO(%O%
```

Explanation:

Uses `Call Set` to update variable during operation of For Loop in conjunction with Substring Modification: `VarName=%VarName:ToSub=SubValue%`.

Substring modification is not case-sensitive - case is determined using the defined For loop set `%%A in (set)`

[image: No TIO Available]

Comment: Given that the input is limited to letters and spaces, could you use `@set o=%*`?

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 70 bytes

```python
lambda s:''.join(l.upper()if l in'aeiouAEIOU'else l.lower()for l in s)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcqxCoMwEAbgVzlckixZ3AodOhTq5CQuLile6JXfXEiU0qePtN/85e/@0tS3SFdaGsL2XAPVizH@rZIs/JEzF@skEkiSCSx63O7DOBlGZYKHfn4havkPqq7lImm30XYPBpRmLVg759oJ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>85</s> 84 bytes

```python
x=''
for i in input():
 if i in'aAeEiIoOuU':x+=i.upper()
 else:x+=i.lower()
print(x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v8JWXZ0rLb9IIVMhMw@ICkpLNDStuBQy08Ai6omOqa6Znvn@paHqVhXatpl6pQUFqUUamlwKqTnFqRChnPxysFBBUWZeiUaF5v//Hqk5OfkK4flFOSkA)

Pretty new to codegolf, so probably not the shortest solution

edit 1: one byte saved because of a space

Comment: Something like [this](https://tio.run/##HYo7CoAwDECv0q3N0sVLeAMHcRBMMRKaEFusp68feMt7PL3LLnnoXY1yCd7HQyiHucWqihaAkmuOsl@RpHrkE19PYn990VoCRJbrmxeA3kdkFjeJ8fYA) gets you 75 bytes, but judging by other Python answers, there are better approaches...

Answer (score 1):

## [SML](https://smlfamily.github.io/) 65 bytes

[Try it!](https://tio.run/##HYwxCgIxEAD7e8Wa6q7wBeEEEUFBsJDDOsSNF9jshmTV58doN1PM1ETbRCrcJCPDYXXFDn@8aYn8tMPbEQSYW3J5DAx@3sUAXlhd5Gr2x/N1cRjlZTzo2juVJWcs4AGpYteLfH46NTvkvlQYA5gTEgncpdBjYybbvg)

```
map(fn c=>if contains"AEIOUaeiou"c then toUpper c else toLower c)
```

This requires `open String` and `open Char`. If those are not allowed, then it would be 87 bytes (`String.map` `Char.contains` `Char.toUpper` `Char.toLower`).

Comment: You can open the libraries, but then those calls are part of the code and should be counted. Thus, in this case it is best to open only `Char` but use `String.map` for 82 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcyxCgIxDIDh3aeIne4GfYGiICJ4IDjI4VxqziukSWgjPn6t4zf8f820y2TCrYkiw3kNxT@sJH7vc9BhYYiHY1ogCltIXN3pMt3ngEk@LoKtvTGZVbFABKSKnTf5/jk2v9F@MhiSgbsikcBTCr22bvTtBw "Standard ML (MLton) – Try It Online")

Comment: 78 bytes by using [this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/150560/56433): [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcyxCgIxDIDh3aeIpcPdoC9QFESEEwQHOZyL5rxCmoQ24uPXjt/w/zXTLpMJtyaKDOc1lvCwkvizz1GHhT0cjmmBl7DFxNWdLtf7HDHJ13lbe2Iyq2LxSBU7bvLrGFvYaL8YDMnATUgk8JRC760bQ/sD "Standard ML (MLton) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Funky2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Funky2), 57 bytes

```
s=>s:gsub("."c=>ifc:match"[aeiou]"c:upper()elsec:lower())
```

Relatively simple solution, benefits from Funky2's relatively concise language.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70srTQvu9JowaI026WlJWm6Fjcti23tiq3Si0uTNJT0lJJt7TLTkq1yE0uSM5SiE1Mz80tjlZKtSgsKUos0NFNzilOTrXLyy0EcTagBM4BGJpdk5ucpFJXmhaQWl2iUAAnNai4FICgoysyDCChoKyjF5MWU2NrFlCgBOWkQZZpctVwwfUoeqTk5-Qrh-UU5KUqaCOHEpOSU1LT0jMys7JzcvPyCwqLiktKy8orKKgVHJ2cXVzd3D08vbx9fP_-AwKDgkNCwiPDIKCWo-xYsgNAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
ḷ{∈Ṿ&ụ|}ᵐ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATAAz/9icmFjaHlsb2cy///huLd74oiI4bm@JuG7pXx94bWQ//8iSEVsbG8gV29ybGQi/1o)

-1 byte thanks to @DLosc.

#### Explanation

```
ḷ             Lowercase the whole input
 {      }ᵐ    Map on each char of the input:
  ∈Ṿ             The char lowercased is in "aeiou"
     &ụ          Output the char uppercased
       |         Or do nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 17 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
1⎕C@(∊∘'aeiou')⎕C
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=M3zUN9XZQeNRR9ejjhnqiamZ@aXqmiAxAA&f=S61IzC3ISS1WeNQ2QUfhUVeTukdqTk6@Qnh@UU6KOlcqTFoHKA@WLslIVSgszUzOVkgqyi/PU0jLr1DwCvUNCFbwD3MNUgjxcFXwcYyKVHDxd8emPTEpOSU1LT0jMys7Jzcvv6CwqLiktKy8orJKwdHJ2cXVzd3D08vbx9fPPyAwKDgkNCwiPDJKnSvt0AoFmGEA&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog&m=dfn&n=f)

A tacit function that ports @Adam's Dyalog Extended solution into vanilla Dyalog APL. Makes use of the system function `⎕C` introduced in Dyalog 18.0 (hence, won't work in TIO).

```
1⎕C@(∊∘'aeiou')⎕C    ⍝ Tacit function.
               ⎕C    ⍝ Convert to lowercase. Then:
1⎕C                  ⍝ Convert to uppercase
   @                 ⍝ at the positions
    (∊∘'aeiou')      ⍝ that are part of the vowels.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA, <s>78</s> 75 bytes

<sup>Saved 3 bytes thanks to Taylor Raine because of course</sup>

```
t=LCase([A1]):For Each c in Split("A E I O U"):t=Replace(t,c,c,,,1):Next:?t
```

Code is run in the immediate window and uses the cell `A1` from the active sheet as it's input. The method is simple:

- Save the lowercase version of the input as `t`
- Save the vowels as `s`
- For each vowel, replace the lowercase version with the uppercase version
- Print the result

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You can use a `For each` loop to get this a bit smaller- `t=[Lower(A1)]:For Each c in Split("A E I O U"):t=Replace(t,c,c,,,1):Next:?t` for 75 bytes

Answer (score 1):

## [Vim](https://www.vim.org), 19 bytes

```
Vu:s/[aeiou]/\U&/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/P6zUqlg/OjE1M780Vj8mVE0/nev//8Sk5JTUtPSMzKzsnNy8/ILCouKS0rLyisoqBUcnZxdXN3cPTy9vH18//4DAoOCQ0LCI8MgoAA)

#### Explanation

```
Vu
```

Select the current line and lowercase it.

```
:s/
```

In the current line, replace...

```
[aeiou]/
```

a vowel character with...

```
\U&/
```

the uppercase version of itself...

```
g<nl>
```

for every match on the line.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 7 bytes

```
ɽƛAß⇧;ṅ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLJvcabQcOf4oenO+G5hSIsIiIsIkFiY2RlZmciXQ==)

```
ɽƛAß⇧;ṅ # Takes the string as input
ɽ       # Lowercase the string
 ƛ   ;  # Map the characters in the string to...
  A     # Is character a vowel?
   ß⇧   # If truthy, uppercase the letter
      ṅ # Join by nothing
```

Comment: -1 byte: `ɽ⟑Aß⇧₴`

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 43 bytes

```arturo
$=>[replace lower&split"aeiou"split"AEIOU"]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?FJAFdV)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-2) `s`, 35 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 4.375 bytes

```
⇩ƛAß⇧
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyI9c34iLCIiLCLih6nGm0HDn+KHpyIsIiIsIkhlbGxvIFdvcmxkIC0+IGhFbGxPIHdPcmxkXG5hYmNkZWZnaGlqa2xtbm9wcXJzdHV2d3h5eiBBQkNERUZHSElKS0xNTk9QUVJTVFVWWFdZWiAtPiBBYmNkRWZnaElqa2xtbk9wcXJzdFV2d3h5eiBBYmNkRWZnaElqa2xtbk9wcXJzdFV2eHd5eiJd)

Bitstring:

```
11010011100001101111110111101101010
```

*minus 6 bits thanks to pacmanboss256*

Posted as a separate answer because a) vyncode isn't a golfing suggestion and b) it's different enough to be its own answer - it's not a byte shave from the other answer.

### Explained (old)

```
ƛA[⇧|⇩
ƛ       # To each character:
 A[     #   if it is a vowel:
   ⇧    #     uppercase
    |   #   else:
     ⇩  #     lowercase
```

Comment: [4.375](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyI9c34iLCIiLCLih6nGm0HDn+KHpyIsIiIsIkhlbGxvIFdvcmxkIC0+IGhFbGxPIHdPcmxkXG5hYmNkZWZnaGlqa2xtbm9wcXJzdHV2d3h5eiBBQkNERUZHSElKS0xNTk9QUVJTVFVWWFdZWiAtPiBBYmNkRWZnaElqa2xtbk9wcXJzdFV2d3h5eiBBYmNkRWZnaElqa2xtbk9wcXJzdFV2eHd5eiJd)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `J`, 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ıDṃh?R:L
```

##### Explanation

```python
ıDṃh?R:L  # Implicit input
ı         # Map over each character
 D        # Duplicate the current character
  ṃh?     # If it's a vowel:
     R    #  Uppercase it
      :   # Otherwise:
       L  #  Lowercase it
          # Implicit output, joined into a string
```

Answer (score 1):

## Swift, <s>95</s> 88 bytes

```swift
let c={($0+"").map{"aeiouAEIOU".contains($0) ?$0.uppercased():$0.lowercased()}.joined()}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 45 bytes

```r
function(s)chartr('aeiou','AEIOU',tolower(s))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcpLFoIgFADQeatg9uAc20ETKyv72c9@M1MIiniFkNXmyek91wZBet0gvCmdQkNrVsrCOkuh4Ao9RBAnaZZD5FBjw20bWBAUJNcaSYNWV8A6LRSXsuLiKtXtrh8Gny9bO/9uPt8fifuDYTIaT9LpbL5YZqv1ZrvL94fj6Qws/AE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 9 bytes

```
LCaRXVUC_
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgwYKlpSVpuhYrfZwTgyLCQp3jIXyo8E2DaKWQjFSFwNLM5GwFp6L88jwFt_wKBa_S3IJiBf-y1CIFkLRPYlWlgkt-up5SLFQjAA)

#### Explanation

```lisp
LCaRXVUC_
LCa        ; Lowercase the input string
   R       ; Replace
    XV     ;  any lowercase vowel
      UC_  ;  with itself uppercased
```

Answer (score 1):

### JS 63 .. 59 Bytes

Hello this is how you can create it in JS using one line of code.

#### Code:

```
f=s=>s.toLowerCase().replace(/[aeiou]/g,v=>v.toUpperCase())
```

#### Test Cases:

1. **Basic Test Cases**:

   - Input: `"Hello"`

     - Expected Output: `"hEllO"`
   - Input: `"Stack Exchange"`

     - Expected Output: `"stAck ExchAngE"`
   - Input: `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"`

     - Expected Output: `"AbcdEfghIjklmnOpqrstUvwxyz"`
2. **Edge Cases**:

   - Input: `""` (Empty string)

     - Expected Output: `""` (Empty string)
   - Input: `"12345"` (No vowels)

     - Expected Output: `"12345"`
   - Input: `"AEIOU"` (All vowels)

     - Expected Output: `"AEIOU"` (All uppercase)
3. **Case Insensitivity Test**:

   - Input: `"HeLLoWorLD"`

     - Expected Output: `"hEllOwOrLD"`
4. **Special Characters Test**:

   - Input: `"@#$%"`

     - Expected Output: `"@#$%"` (No vowels, no change expected)
   - Input: `"hello$world"`

     - Expected Output: `"hEllO$wOrld"` (Vowels in the middle of the string)
5. **Long String Test**:

   - Input: `"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."`

     - Expected Output: `"lOrEm IpsUm dOlOr sIt AmEt, cOnsEc tEtUr AdIpIscIng ElIt. sEd dO EIUsmOd tEmpOr IncIdIdUnt Ut lAbOrE Et dOlOrE MAgnA AlIqUA."`
6. **Performance Test**:

   - Input: `"a" repeated 10^6 times (a million times)`

     - Expected Output: `"A"` repeated 10^6 times
   - Input: `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"` repeated 10^4 times

     - Expected Output: `"AbcdEfghIjklmnOpqrstUvwxyz"` repeated 10^4 times
7. **Random Test Cases**:

   - Input: `"hElLo!"`

     - Expected Output: `"hEllO!"` (Only 'e' should be capitalized)
   - Input: `"HeLlO 123"`

     - Expected Output: `"hEllO 123"` (Only vowels should be capitalized)
   - Input: `"rAnDoMT3XT"`

     - Expected Output: `"rAndOmt3xt"` (Only 'a' and 'o' should be capitalized)

#### Try it Online:

```js
f=s=>s.toLowerCase().replace(/[aeiou]/g,v=>v.toUpperCase())

// Test Cases
function runTest(input, expectedOutput) {
    const output = f(input);
    console.log("Input:", input);
    console.log("Expected Output:", expectedOutput);
    console.log("Actual Output:", output);
    if (output === expectedOutput) {
        console.log("Test Passed!");
    } else {
        console.log("Test Failed!");
    }
    console.log("-------------------------");
}

// Basic Test Cases
runTest("Hello", "hEllO");
runTest("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", "AbcdEfghIjklmnOpqrstUvwxyz");

// Edge Cases
runTest("", "");
runTest("12345", "12345");
runTest("AEIOU", "AEIOU");

// Case Insensitivity Test
runTest("HeLLoWorLD", "hEllOwOrld");

// Special Characters Test
runTest("@#$%", "@#$%");
runTest("hello$world", "hEllO$wOrld");

// Long String Test
runTest("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.", "lOrEm IpsUm dOlOr sIt AmEt, cOnsEctEtUr AdIpIscIng ElIt. sEd dO EIUsmOd tEmpOr IncIdIdUnt Ut lAbOrE Et dOlOrE mAgnA AlIqUA.");

// Performance Test
runTest("a".repeat(1e6), "A".repeat(1e6));
runTest("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".repeat(1e4), "AbcdEfghIjklmnOpqrstUvwxyz".repeat(1e4));

// Random Test Cases
runTest("hElLo!", "hEllO!");
runTest("HeLlO 123", "hEllO 123");
runTest("rAnDoMT3XT", "rAndOmt3xt");
```

Comment: Nice answer, and welcome. You can remove all of the spaces in your code. Also, iirc in JS, it'll still compile/run even without the leading `const ` and trailing semi-colon, so it can be `f=s=>s.toLowerCase().replace(/[aeiou]/g,v=>v.toUpperCase())` (59 bytes).

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt reply.

Answer (score 0):

## [Lexurgy](https://www.lexurgy.com/sc), 111 bytes

Simple replacement

```
a:
{a,e,i,o,u,B,C,D,F,G,H,J,K,L,M,N,P,Q,R,S,T,V,W,X,Y,Z}=>{A,E,I,O,U,b,c,d,f,g,h,j,k,l,m,n,p,q,r,s,t,v,w,x,y,z}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 64 bytes

```lua
print(((...):lower():gsub('[aeiou]',load'return(...):upper()')))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcrBCYAwDADAVfwlAekATuAGPsRHpUEKoSmxwfEj4r1PPEd0q20gYkqJFtGHDWm5bj8R9sxV/YBZNBcwHm7tf97794CIImJlEZ02NSkv)

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3) `s`, 5 bytes

```
ʀƛA¿ɾ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyJzIiwiIiwiyoDGm0HCv8m+IiwiIiwiSGVsbG8gV29ybGQiLCIzLjQuMCJd)

lowercase the entire string then uppercase the vowels

Answer (score 0):

## [Gema](http://gema.sourceforge.net/), 36 characters

```
/[aeiou]/=@upcase{$0}
?=@downcase{?}
```

Sample run:

```
bash-5.2$ gema '/[aeiou]/=@upcase{$0};?=@downcase{?}' <<< 'Hello World'
hEllO wOrld
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/NTfz/Xz86MTUzvzRW39ahtCA5sTi1WsWglsve1iElvzwPzLev/f/fIzUnJ18hPL8oJwUA)

Answer (score 0):

## Swift, 125 bytes

Short version:

```
func c(_ t:String)->String{return t.lowercased().map({String($0)}).map({"aeiou".contains($0) ?$0.uppercased():$0}).joined()}
```

Verbose version:

```
func c2 (_ t: String) -> String {
    let s = t.map({String($0).lowercased()})
    let lv = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]

    let r = s.map { l in
        lv.contains(l) ? l.uppercased() : l
    }.joined()
    
    return r
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## APL(NARS), 45 chars

```
{⍵∊⎕A∼'AEIOU':⎕a[⎕A⍸⍵]⋄⍵∊'aeiou':⎕A[⎕a⍸⍵]⋄⍵}¨
```

test & how to use:

```
      f←{⍵∊⎕A∼'AEIOU':⎕a[⎕A⍸⍵]⋄⍵∊'aeiou':⎕A[⎕a⍸⍵]⋄⍵}¨
      f 'Hello World' 
hEllO wOrld
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) <sup>[SBCS](https://tinyurl.com/Uiua-SBCS-Jan-14)</sup>, 14 bytes

```
¯⍜▽¯∊,"AEIOU"⌵
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_8_0__ZiDihpAgwq_ijZzilr3Cr-KIiiwiQUVJT1Ui4oy1CgpmICJIZWxsbyBXb3JsZCIKZiAiYWJjZGVmZ2hpamtsbW5vcHFyc3R1dnd4eXogQUJDREVGR0hJSktMTU5PUFFSU1RVVlhXWVoiCg==)

0.9.0 recently extended `abs` and `negate` to work on characters, making this much easier.

```
¯⍜▽¯∊,"AEIOU"⌵
             ⌵  # uppercase the input
    ∊,"AEIOU"   # mask of vowels
 ⍜▽¯            # swap case at indices given by the mask
¯               # swap case
```

Answer (score 0):

## [YASEPL](https://github.com/madeforlosers/YASEPL-esolang/), <s>155</s> <s>147</s> 145 bytes

```
=2)"aeiouAEIOU"±""=1'=i=l®1`1=k=f=m¥i,1`9!y¥f,2!m}7,y,8!k$`8!f+}2,10,9=j`2!j+!q$j»}7,m,2`3!j}1,90,5}2,65,5!f$j+32|6`5!f$j`6!k[7!f-32`7!f›!i+}2,l
```

i mistakenly uploaded this without testing my code. whoopsies, heres a fixed version

Answer (score -1):

## Python 3, 82 bytes

```py
f=lambda c:c.upper()if c in 'aeiou'else c.lower();lambda s:''.join(map(f,list(s)))
```