# Filthy and Unique

Tags: code-challenge, pristine-programming

In this question I will talk about programs as strings, this is strings of bytes, not characters.  How your resultant program is rendered or displayed is not important to this challenge, only how it appears in memory matters.

A [pristine program](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/63433/programming-a-pristine-world) is a program \$S\$ that when run does not error, however it will error whenever a continuous substring of size \$n\$, where \$1\leq n < \left|S\right|\$, is removed.

A filthy program is the opposite, it is a program \$S\$ that when run *does* error, however whenever a continuous substring of size \$n\$, where \$1\leq n < \left|S\right|\$, is removed, it does not error.

For this challenge an error is non-empty output to STDERR.

Your challenge is to write a filthy program that uses as many unique bytes as possible.  This means you will get one point for every unique byte that appears in your code with a larger score being better.  The maximum score is thus 256.

Comment: Is it even possible to answer this in languages that involve brackets/parentheses? It would be possible to remove some substring from code so that there would be mismatched brackets.

Comment: @JungHwanMin If the language enforces balanced parentheses I would suspect that it would be impossible.

Comment: @CatWizard so a filthy program does not error when a continuous substring of characters (i.e. **not** continuous set of bytes) is removed, correct?

Comment: @JungHwanMin Sorry.  It may or may not.  We only care about continuous strings.

Comment: What's the intention of the first paragraph of the question ("this is strings of bytes, not characters")? Is it to say individual bytes have to be removable and the program should still work? For eg., if I used `π` in my program, does it have to work when individual bytes of it (0xcf and 0x80) are removed?

Comment: @sundar The intention of the first paragraph is to make clear that it doesn't matter what characters your program encodes, only what is actually encoded.  If you use `π` in your program you are using two bytes, it doesn't matter that they only display as one character under some encodings, they are separate bytes, and are treated no different than for example `a%` which is also two bytes.

Comment: Does leading or trailing whitespace count towards the bytes?

Comment: @ngm Yes it does.

Comment: "For this challenge an error is a non-empty output to STDERR". Compiler errors count as well, right?

Comment: @Jakob Yes, both compiler errors and runtime errors both count.

Comment: [This script generates all the programs necessary to check](https://tio.run/##HY29CsIwFIX3PMUFwUUpWJ0KtRRc6qhjCCG2oQncJqW5rYj47LHpmc7PB0cRqdboGKsKxsk6CqAQV@v7SQ0B3sa2BoLxM3bw0kA6kO4YCzRBUUKN2LhxJi4YWxTaLpVfBqvu3jooryD5FpMeevCLrgfv@n0h87Q@0bY6cJkf4ZRl2U6KjRbst2s8KcZuNoyoPondDvj6LGI8Hy5/ "Attache – Try It Online")

Comment: @ConorO'Brien maybe there is a way to do that with Bash on TIO to test them automatically? I don't know Bash or if there is a `try` and `except` construct.

Comment: @dylnan Bash can check for exit code, but that won't work for languages which doesn't use exit code to indicate error. However if it's possible to do it natively it's often faster.

Answer (score 21):

## [Unary](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Unary), 14 bytes

```
123456789ABCDE
```

This encodes the brainfuck program `[`, which errors due to unmatched brackets.

Removing bytes will result in `>`, `<`, `+`, `-`, `.`, `,` or the empty program, which are valid brainfuck programs.

Comment: This is the optimal solution, since any longer solution could be reduced to this solution, which errors

Comment: This is also the only solution.

Answer (score 16):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 3 bytes

```r
qrt
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7Co5P9/AA)

A name of an object is a valid program in R.

`qrt` is not the name of anything, so it returns an error.

`q` is the quit function

`qr` is the QR decomposition function

`rt` is the t distribution sampling function

`qt` is the t distribution inverse CDF

`t` is the transpose function

Comment: @pajonk but "r" is a continuous substring. Removing that leaves "qt"

Comment: There is exactly one filthy program in R of length 3, and this is it! (the only single char valid programs are `0-9cqtCDFIT`, any program must therefore start with `cm`, `qf`, `qr`, `qt`, `ts` or `Im`. The length three possibilities are `qrf`,`qrm`,`qrt`,`qts` and `tsd` and only one of these is filthy (the others can't be extended either to make them filthy as there are no functions `rm*`,`rf*`,`ts*`,`sd*`)

Comment: @Orphevs my bad, misread the challenge.

Comment: Note that, following Arnauld's strategy (see 'Polyglot' answer), there are actually 101  filthy programs in R of length 3: this one, plus 100 more of the form ```1  2``` (where each of the two digits can be substituted with any of the other 9 possible digits).

Answer (score 13):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>4 5 6 7 8 10</s> 11 bytes

```
“a”;⁽PFð+µU
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw5zERw1zrR817g1wO7xB@9DW0P//AQ)

[Verify it.](https://tio.run/##dVG9TsMwEN79FJYYkihRlYitKJUY2hGxMJWqCs0VjBw7ctyKbmVnY0Jq34GFgYEFnoS8SGrHpm4o3JDcXb4f@0u5knecnTYznkPqeV693mT1entWP35cjr5ew8@3K7Vt5oIX@B4oXWFSlFxIM0xhmVGs6wRntOCV1P2xxvf7S4IsUZICEJJxqpuefvgBQoyzoRBcVDjFMQLXojkXuJKZYhKGRcZuwafAfH3gIEyCPtKWGgQsd5CWESaRg5rVIA4sRZf@MpWCFAXkyk2P436Lm@DQjEq1P9kTpFg5ti4B1YJKxXV5@Ieq0XgS7AnwMINSdgXsVcMUJ519KQiTHakDHVpBV8XF1xFCyMh418yL1E3UH1ZZk7l1HcRGxYLOb/gS8E8c2trierjePimm87WMC/4PfPOsjfZp/QqnDcWEgYfti3DWER4tKP1L8ugEDphzqFQO0jDskZtmBw)

Tries to add a string with an integer.

Some of the possible subprograms:

`“a”` is a string literal.

`“a` is the same string literal.

`“` is the empty string.

`“a”;` concatenates "a" with itself.

...too many to enumerate them all.

Comment: Fortunately Jelly still allows you to error.

Answer (score 7):

## Polyglot, 3 bytes

```javascript
1 2
```

Works in:

- JavaScript
- Ruby
- R
- Octave
- GHCi
- Julia

In JavaScript, throws *SyntaxError: unexpected token: numeric literal* or a similar error.

All other strings are valid numeric literals (**1**, **2**, or **12**).

---

In GHCi this throws

```javascript
<interactive>:1:1: error:
    • Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num (t1 -> t2)
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    • When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall t1 t2. (Num t1, Num (t1 -> t2)) => t2
```

This is because it tries to apply `1` to `2` as a function, however it cannot.  When any part of this is removed it simply becomes a numeric literal.

Comment: Polyglot: R, Octave, Ruby, the Pythons...

Comment: @ngm GHCi as well, however ` 2` errors in python.

Comment: I suspected that it was very generic. I've turned this into community wiki, so feel free to edit with all languages for which this works!

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 2 bytes

#### Unexpected character after line continuation character

```python
\0
```

`\` followed by any of `123456789 #`
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYw9CoAwDIX3niJbFgdxFDyJdZCYYkHa0lTQ09coBZf398FLd9ljGGqluLHABDNa22OnqvIGXIyLGV4OPnwuo4GUfShfM1DyrQvwxdSWhlFOIhZBo5A4lfFHbvUHth/EWh8)

#### Invalid octal number

```python
08
```

`0` followed by any of `89`
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYwxCoAwEAT7vOK6bSzETsGXiIWcJwYkCbkI@voYJWCxLDsDG@60e9flzH4VpZEmtD0atCVvYzabj/Rasu5rHQyFaF36lqEU70JILuFKqoaezKIKUyRLSMOvtsUeqD9Azg8)

#### Unexpected Indent

```python
 0
```

or `\t` followed by any of `123456789\`
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYwxCsMwFEN3n0KbliztGOhJQobw80MNxTb@LiSndx1j6CCE3gOlq7xjeNYqcVfDCwvx4ES03M3VHTHjtvCht80OKftQ@nIo@WoEeqoMMjTtK6JmdE2KpjL/1bH5D8cPWesP)

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2/3](https://docs.python.org), 3 bytes

```
4\f2
```

OR

```
4\x0c2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBNb4MwDIbv@RUWvYCK0Fb21Uo9UKSddpp2zCUNRqBFCXLCtP56lgAb3YaVSNHj145fdxfXGL0bhgprwE@UvRNnhbFNDgx8RFH0iq4nDW0Nrmkt@LPoQJoKMy8axY4uU1WIIPJt2PSW2LklR1PLZ6EssivwRj2yDbwY8w61IchBNoKEdEg284lie9qW4wREhjIodBVY6mlahJuWYBvTqwqEUnBG@BCqrTLGgj2LgmSTx7M1BUeIuOOa15xgc3uzy@/uHx6f9pxPdsIEBbQa1DJ5YKc/7JuXKzyE35w27nq7o48EhB//N50Y/9di3ucsXC8uk8NaHXTUahcTdjT/mzD2s4ph@AI)

In python "\f" is the same as "\x0c" and is a [form feed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_break#Form_feed) character. This means that it indicates for a printer to go to the next line.

If a python expression starts or ends with `\f`, it is basically ignored so `\f2` is a valid expression.

The `4` and `2` can be any number 0-9. However, for the first byte to be `0` is only valid in Python 2.7.15, as `02` was made a legal declaration of `2`.

So the expression itself fails with a Syntax Error, because there are two numbers separated by a whitespace. However, any shortening either puts `\f` at the beginning or end, where it doesn't matter, or it creates `42` which is valid.

(It is worth noting that in IDLE this file opens looking like "42".)

Form feed explanation source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26184126

Comment: This would be easier to understand if you used the actual code in the source without the `\f`.  [Here](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/34QHSAAA "Python 2 – Try It Online") is a try it online link from which you can get a pre-formatted answer.

Comment: I have added it as a variant for clarification. Also, thank you for the suggestion of the link.

Answer (score 4):

## [Dyalog APL](https://www.dyalog.com/), 5 bytes ([SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS))

```apl
~≢0 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v@5R5yIDBcP//wE)
or
[test all the possible programs](https://tio.run/##XVLbbtNAEH33V4yKVANNlKTcI0Dc7/c7CFGZZBtMnTi1HUoIqVBBke14K1oE5YVb2opQISEIUaASQkr@5PxImI3fkLzenZkzZ88crVG2kvmqYdmFIeQ7MizLnhP5rKaCKeN@Li@mCw/MhzNWsWSXZx3Xqzyae1x9Avk1nZncsXPX7j179yFsHT5y9NjxEydPnT5z9tz5CxcvXb5y9dr1Gzdv3b6DcBVRL4Xo713IZ/sRrB1AsH4QwUf4bfifkxOD3mAFfgj5cx6NJTReQXaw0tyOyEcUIlxA@Bz@F/gbCNcRrj1NQH6H/AG5DNmEDBD9QfgG8gOi35CvIRchNxB8QtAa/Noyfg/@KmQPzRdovERjGYsMea/xyMQJ4lE0T7jeKKhpRGkW2ILsZlWJlBGiWPaqlLPzgkyXXM8xSgVB41SyPXLEbMV0RJ4bi26BOXRFZpYKNKYTK@0mSB/L6oqXslniWxNKRrig4KQLx7G5W9WnVF5p73LwP86t5HLCdXWtrk2bliccLta2Qm7y129zz7YU/@pDJVKJmOcZ0pTR49FUVisbjufGU7KjiVSNG2r9b5kJ3nl1FE1HRZtJRTUK1SF2ox6TjOj6babgrP82TbEaSh9iDPFLGMHqCjK6T1NuK9uX1BMb/gM)

There sure are better boring answers, but this is the best non-boring one I've found

SBCS is required as Dyalog Classic seems to always have output in STDERR, making it unusable.

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 2 bytes

```
:#
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwYKlpSVpuhaLrJQhDCgfJg4A)

Zsh is very good at producing errors, so this challenge is very hard.

- `:` on its own is command which does nothing
- `#` is a comment
- `:#` is a single command, which doesn't exist, and therefore errors. (`#` is only a comment when it's at the start of a word)